# Apply iOS update to multiple devices

Tags: ios, itunes

I am in the process of downloading iOS9 for my iPhone5S on iTunes. This is taking 90 minutes. I also have an iPad and my wife has an iPhone4 and an iPad (she syncs these to her MacBook).

Is there any way of using the single download to update the 4 devices.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Apple doesn't have a universal iOS installer to download and install to multiple devices.

Answer (score 0):

Each iDevice has its own specific ipsw (installer) file.